# reactjs + spring security, registration part failed getting 403 error

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

  @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH").allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

}

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors()
    .and().csrf()
    .disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/",
             "/favicon.ico",
             "/**/*.png",
             "/**/*.gif",
             "/**/*.svg",
             "/**/*.jpg",
             "/**/*.html",
             "/**/*.css",
             "/**/*.js")
             .permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/registration", "/login")
             .permitAll().anyRequest()
             .authenticated();;
}
```

[image]

when sending an request from reactjs, I'm getting the error showed in the screenshot. I think it is related to CrossOrigin issue. Please help

Comment: Try adding OPTIONS method to your CORS configuration as well. It might be failing because of the pre-flight request.

Comment: Your client and your server are the same `http://localhost:8000`, hence it is no CORS problem. Show your full Spring Security configuration, not only one method.